Proof of the Derivative of Parametric Equations
My question is identical to this post.
In summary, my textbook proves the following statement:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}
$$
They assume that y can be expressed as a function of x to prove this statement. However, in my brief experience, I realized this re-expression is not always possible. So, how does this statement hold in general? That is, how does this statement also hold for curves whose y values cannot be re-expressed as a function of x-values?
In the other post, a now-deleted commenter appeared to resolve the question, showing that the cycloid (a parametric curve whose y values cannot be expressed as a function of x) does satisfy this condition. Unless I am missing something, this seems insufficient to prove that the above statement holds for all curves whose y values cannot be expressed as a function of x.

Implicit function theorem

It is a bit difficult to answer the question "how does this statement hold in general ?", because the statement is somewhat informal. A short answer would probably be : as soon as the function $t \mapsto x(t)$ is bijective and $x'(t) \neq 0$. To see why, let us rewrite things more carefully.
Firstly, the $y$-values of the cycloid,
$$
x(t) = t - \sin(t),\quad 
y(t) = 1 - \cos(t)
$$
can, in fact, be given as a function of the $x$-values : that is, there does exist a function $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$y(t) = F(x(t)) \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
It happens that there is no closed-form expression for this function, but that doesn't mean the function is less legitimate, and that we can't compute its derivative.
One way to define rigourously the function $F$ is as follows. Observe that $\frac{dx}{dt} = 1 - \cos(t) \geq 0$, so $t\mapsto x(t)$ is increasing, and is therefore a bijection from $[0,+\infty[$ to $[0,+\infty[$. Thus, one can consider the reciprocal function $t^*: [0,+\infty[ \to [0,+\infty[$, defined by $t^*(x(t)) = t$ and $x(t^*(x)) = x$. In words, $t^*(x)$ is the time at which the cycloid reaches the abscissa $x$. The function $F$ above is then given by
$$F(x) := y(t^*(x)).$$
Indeed, applying $F$ to $x(t)$ gives exactly $y(t)$ by definition of $t^*$.
Now, by differentiating $t^*(x(t)) = t$ on both sides, and using the chain rule, we see that
$$(t^*)'(x(t)) \cdot x'(t) = 1 \implies (t^*)'(x) = \frac{1}{x'(t^*(x))}$$
(this is the well-known formula $(f^{-1})' = \frac{1}{f'\circ f^{-1}}$).
Thus, since $F(x) = y(t^*(x))$, we get
$$F'(x) = y'(t^*(x)) (t^*)'(x) = \frac{y'(t^*(x))}{x'(t^*(x))} \implies F(x(t)) = \frac{y'(t)}{x'(t)}.$$
The above is exactly what is meant by $dy/dx = \frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt}$.

I mean general, as in how does the above statement hold for all functions, not just curves that can be rewritten so that y is a function of x and not just the cycloid?

My interest is not in the cycloid but generally in curves that cannot be rewritten so that y is a function of x (in a closed-form expression). Are you saying that all curves can be written so that y is a function of x if we include non-closed-form expressions? @Martin

Just to be clear, what I mean when I say informal, is not your question, but the statement $dy/dx = \frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$. For example, $y$ denotes both functions $t \mapsto y(t)$ and $x \mapsto y(x)$ in that formula.
Now to your comment, yes I'm saying that this is the case as soon as $x(t)$ is a bijective function, and, say, $C^1$, and $x'(t) \neq 0$ (with the same proof : look at the structure of it). Very informally, this means $t$ can be written as $t(x)$ and thus $y(t) = y(t(x)) = y(x)$. $x'(t) \neq 0$ is just to make sure that $y'(x)$ is defined.
